# Find the infimum and supremum of the set $G = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2+x+1>0\}$.

Tags: real-analysis, solution-verification, supremum-and-infimum

Find the infimum and supremum of the set $G = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2+x+1>0\}$.

**Attempt:**
For all real $x$, the discriminant is $1^2-4(1)(1) =-3<0$. So, for all real $x$ has $x^2+x+1>0$ i.e. $G = \Bbb R$.

Hence, $G = (-\infty,\infty)$ and hence, $\inf G = -\infty$ and $\sup G = \infty$.

But, for another consideration, for all real $x$, we have $x^2+x+1 = (x+\frac{1}{2})^2 + \frac{3}{4} \ge \frac{3}{4}$, which equality attained when $x = - \frac{1}{2}$. Therefore, $\inf G = \frac{3}{4}$ and $\sup G = \infty$.

What should I do?

Comment: The second method also proves that Inf G which is the infimum of x such that the polynomial is positive is -infinity. You’re thinking of $\inf_{x\in\mathbb R}(x^2+x+1)$ which is completely different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you are mixing two different things here whose notations seem similar
(and maybe that's what confused you) but they are not the same thing.

$G_1 = \{x \in \Bbb R \mid x^2+x+1>0\}$

$G_2 = \{x^2+x+1 \mid x \in \Bbb R \}$

Note that $$G_1 = \Bbb R$$ while

$$G_2 = [3/4; \infty)$$

So $$\inf G_2 = 3/4$$

and so there is no contradiction here or any logical issue.